# If a chemical reaction is repeated multiple times, will it produce the same result?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

If a chemical reaction is repeated multiple(infinity) times, will it produce the same result?

For example, I put two $\ce{H}$ and one $\ce{O}$ together, and repeat it many (infinity) times within an exact **same** environment, will it produce $\ce{H2O}$ every time?

My chemistry teacher tells me it **will**. But I still wonder if it's true. Hope you will help me. Thanks.

Comment: You may also get a noble prize for being able to generate a molecules using atoms :-D. jokes apart, why do you think something different will happen?

Comment: If I remember correctly this is one aspect of selectivity or in catalysis. If two products can form in a reaction both have an activation energy. Even though your catalyst might give you one of two possible products only you are not allowed to call it 100% but you will always find 99% or so. That is because for reaction A to be 100% selective reaction B would require an infinately high activation barrier. If that is not the case then upon repeating it for infinate runs you will also get the second product. Please correct me if I'm wrong here but it's been a while.

Comment: @Safdar Emm, you must know *Uncertainty Principle*. I think the atoms move uncertainty and it may cause different results. Maybe I'm naive, but forgive me.

Comment: Some reactions generate side products, which are produced with less abundance than the primary product. perhaps that is what you are looking for.

Comment: However uncertainly they move, the only way a reaction happens is if they collide with each other. Here taking what you have, I would say that there would be other products $\ce{H + H -> H2}$,$\ce{H + H + O->H2O}$. This is assuming there are only 2 atoms of H and one atom of O. if you have a mixture of a very high number of H and O atoms other products like $\ce{H2O2, O2}$ can also form. Only issue here is that they do not exist as atoms and do not wish to remain so. So if you have a reaction conditions where only $\ce{H2O}$ can form, then only $\ce{H2O}$ will form for that reaction condition.

Comment: The uncertainty principle, you must know, is referred to the information arising for a single (or a few) particles. When studying many particles, the uncertainty principle becomes irrelevant, and macroscopic statistics gets it shape. What is a mole of "particles"?

Comment: @Safdar Ah,thanks. Moreover, if I have two $\ce{H}$ and two $\ce{O}$, it can get $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O}$ or $\ce{H2O2}$. So there's two results?

Comment: They are *possible* not certain.. However for a given set of reaction conditions, you would get the same yield assuming you do everything perfectly.

Comment: @Safdar You mean, if I do every perfectly, it will only result the same?

Comment: Yes. Maintaing the same conditions, extracting the product in the exact same manner and so on would give the same product at the same yield.

Comment: @Safdar Thanks. This will happen in macrography or every time(include micrography)?

Comment: @ Sir Kay. The Uncertainty Principle states that no parameters related to a single particule can be measured with precision at the same time. For example, if you determine the position of a particule at time t, the speed cannot be known with precision at the same time. It has nothing to do with your problem

Comment: There are some kinds of reactions which display mathematical chaos even on a macroscopic scale (e.g. the [Belousov-Zhabotinsky oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction)), and in a rough sense, could be said to *never* produce the same macroscopic result, even for reactions run with the exact same conditions (up to the uncertainty principle).

Comment: @Maurice Doesn't it, really? Tell what it says is not understanding consequences, and one is that you never know the state of system with absolute precision and therefore it's impossible to duplicate it with such precision and OP's question is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a difficult question because some of the terms are not as well-defined as one might like.

What constitutes an experiment and what constitutes repeatable?

A experiment isn't just what you are doing but also requires an observable. It's unclear how repeatable certain setups are. You can try to eliminate variables, but you're limited in exactness. For the observable, you're limited by accuracy of detection and also by the fact that observations may change the system under observation.

You have to consider the quantum mechanical aspect as well. For example, if you try to measure the maximum occupancy of electrons in a given orbital, the answer is two, you will be unable to measure anything else because it is forbidden under quantum mechanics (assuming the model is correct). On the other hand, the uncertainty principle will make certain measurements and setups unreasonable, though you *might* be able to get around those facts with clever experiments.

There is also the issue that much of chemistry is driven by stochastic processes which we model fairly well with statistical mechanics. What are you supposed to get if you measure the temperature of a glass of water? Well, in a large enough sample, it will be fairly close to some value, but there are very small fluctuations around that value that are not easy for us to detect. But in the limit of infinite measurements over infinite time, you might see a random large fluctuation. Is that temperature measurement still repeatable? Practically yes, but in theory, not necessarily.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on whether you are looking at the level of a single atom or a large population of atoms. Because of quantum effects, there is a lot of randomness in the behavior of single atoms. If there are multiple possible outcomes, we can fairly accurately determine the *probability* of each outcome, but which outcome occurs is not predetermined.

With a large population of atoms (such as we have in any normal laboratory experiment like the ones your teacher is talking about), the large sample size means that we get the same result every time if we control every relevant variable (which is actually quite hard to do).

Answer (score 2):

In radical chemistry, one can obtain varying results with the same starting radicals. The products do, however, appear to follow a consistent probabilistic level of respective yields for each product.

To help clarify, a set of radical reactions around the ∙ClO dimer, for example:

$\ce{∙OCl + ∙OCl = (OCl)2 or (ClO)2 }$  (support on the existence of the latter, see, for example, [Eq(14) here](https://www.scielo.br/pdf/jbchs/v23n8/aop053_12.pdf))

$\ce{∙OCl + ∙OCl = ∙ClOO + ∙Cl }$

$\ce{∙OCl + ∙OCl = ∙OClO + ∙Cl }$

And, as:

$\ce{ ∙Cl + ∙Cl = Cl2 }$

One can also find the cited reaction:

$\ce{∙OCl + ∙OCl = O2 + Cl2 }$

And even:

$\ce{∙OCl + ∙OCl = Cl2O2 }$

Source: See https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/j100286a035?journalCode=jpchax .

where above ∙OClO is commonly cited as ClO2 (chlorine dioxide).

In general, an area of study where one experiences a range of products upon the photolysis of a compound commonly occurs in the field of photochemistry.

[EDIT] More completely, I would further cite cyclic reaction systems displaying periodicity. Examples include the action of H2O2 with HCl, and much more famously, [Iodine Clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iodine_clock_reaction) reaction systems, where one can visually see decisive variations in reaction products occurring over time.

Answer (score 1):

The most essential thing of all sciences, that they apply to the laws of the nature, independently from space and time.

It is not even for chemistry. That burning $\ce{H2}$ in $\ce{O2}$ makes water (in the common pressure/temperature), is similarly so in our current best knowledge, than for example, the laws of the Newtonian mechanics.

If it would not be so, then the search for the more general laws, saying why, when and how the result of the repeated experiments differ, is started on the spot.